# Create Timesheet view for sign in data from the table Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In my ASP.NET MVC Web application, in the database table, I stored the system login date and time for the users.

This is my Model

```
public class UserLog
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Login_Date { get; set; }
        public string PC_Name { get; set; }
        public string PC_User_Name { get; set; }
    }
```

So to the view, I want to pass the selected month Dates ( start date to end date ) to the view also from this model example: 01-10-2022 if data has in the table, then the login date must be shown in front of the date.

So far I tried but not figure out how to do it.

What I currently did was, get the data for a list first.(data list 1)

Then again got data for the selected month's start date to end date. (data list 2)

So then I tried from the monthly data list (data list 2) to exclude the (data list 1) and get the data that did not match with the DB table and show those dates separately on the view.

Any solution for this?

This is my controller

```
var startDate = new DateTime(attendanceVM.MonthYear.Year, attendanceVM.MonthYear.Month, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
int EmpId = int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);
//Get the data from the database table for the selected user selected month
IEnumerable < AttendanceResults > resutls = (from l in db.UserLog where l.Emp_Id == EmpId && l.Login_Date >= startDate && l.Login_Date <= endDate select new AttendanceResults {
      Id = l.Id,
      Date = l.Login_Date,
      Acc_Name = l.PC_User_Name,
      PC_Name = l.PC_Name
    }).ToList();

//Get the selected month all Dates
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days).Select(dayOffset => startDate.AddDays(dayOffset)).ToList();

//Exclude from the month all dates that not matching with the database date records. (method 1) didn't worked. returns all the dates again
var notInRange = range.Except(resutls.Select(r => r.Date)).ToList();

//Exclude from the month all dates that not matching with the database date records. (method 2) idn't worked. returns all the dates again
List < DateTime > dateTimes = range.Where(x => !resutls.Select(a => a.Date).Contains(x.Date)).ToList();

return PartialView("_AttendanceSheet", resutls);
```

This is how I wanted to get the final view. (sharing to get an idea for you)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. A little bit changed how to work with date range.

```cs
var startDate = new DateTime(attendanceVM.MonthYear.Year, attendanceVM.MonthYear.Month, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);

int EmpId = int.Parse(((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity).FindFirst("UserId").Value);

//Get the data from the database table for the selected user selected month
var databaseData = (
    from l in db.UserLog 
    where l.Emp_Id == EmpId && l.Login_Date >= startDate && l.Login_Date < endDate 
    select new AttendanceResults 
    {
        Id = l.Id,
        Date = l.Login_Date,
        Acc_Name = l.PC_User_Name,
        PC_Name = l.PC_Name
    }).ToList();

//Get the selected month all Dates
var rangeDates = Enumerable.Range(0, endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days)
    .Select(dayOffset => startDate.AddDays(dayOffset));

// fill gaps
var results = 
    from rd in rangeDates
    join d in databaseData on rd equals d.Date.Date into gj
    from d in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select d ?? new AttendanceResults { Date = rd }; 

return PartialView("_AttendanceSheet", resutls);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. But for the result list, it didn't pass the data that wanted. All the data from the month is passed to the ``results``. I wonder what happens to the ``range dates`` formats like ``10-01-2022 12.00 AM`` where the database data ``Date`` returns ``10-01-2022 09:16 AM``.

Comment: Corrected join condition. But it may produce duplicate dates. What to do with them?